# Firebase 'array-contains-any' more than 10 elements

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array field stored on documents in my Firestore collection and I need to be able to pull each document where the array field contains one of several options. I only need each match one time so if the array field contains multiple items from the options I still only need one copy of that document to be returned. Currently I am structuring the query like this:

```
query = collection.WhereArrayContainsAny('array-field', [1,2,3,4,...]);
```

The problem I am running into is that the provided array of options is over 10 items so the query is failing. I could split the options array into 10 element arrays and run the query multiple times but I worry that it will make the query take a very long time to execute and speed is important. Is there any way around this 10-item limit that has worked for people in the past?

Comment: it increased until 100 queries now due to official doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run multiple query calls in parallel and combine the results in a single list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int failed = 0;
      var tasks = new List<Task<QuerySnapshot>>();
      String[] filters = {1,2,3,4,5};
      
      foreach (var value in filters) {
    
         tasks.Add(Task.Run( async () => { 
           
                                     try {
                                       Query query = collection.WhereArrayContainsAny('array-field', [value]);
                                       QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await museums.GetSnapshotAsync();
                                       return querySnapshot;
                                       
                                     }
                                     catch (Exception) {
                                        // handle exception
                                        throw;
                                     }
                                   })
                                   );
      }
      var continuation = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
      try {
         continuation.Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException)
      { }
   
      if (continuation.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
         List<QuerySnapshot> queries = new List<QuerySnapshot>()

        

         foreach (var result in continuation.Result) {
             foreach (DocumentSnapshot document in result.Documents){
              queries.add(document);
          }     
         }
  
      }
      // Display information on faulted tasks.
      else {
         foreach (var t in tasks) {
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
         }
      }      
   }
}
```